# Is this right way to show ad?

Tags: android, admob

Is this right way to show ad on click ? than go to next activity

```
mUrlAdButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
            mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    Intent zintent = new Intent(mContext, Main2Activity.class);
                    zintent.putExtra("url", mUrl);
                    zintent.putExtra("title", pTitle);
                    mContext.startActivity(zintent);
                 mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                }
            });
        } else {
                Intent zintent = new Intent(mContext, Main2Activity.class);
                zintent.putExtra("url", mUrl);
                zintent.putExtra("title", pTitle);
                mContext.startActivity(zintent);
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
    }
});
```

sometimes pressing the X button will not go to the next activity

Comment: When you press button at a time your ad will shown or not?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems absolutely fine for me. I too use such ways while testing apps.

But I would suggest one thing, initialize the intent outside the Button's click listener and only add the start activity and the load new add into adclosed and else block.